# How to use `then` block in spock test

Tags: testing, spock

I'm new to spock and have gone through the documentation but still do not fully understand how to use the `then` section. If I want to compare two strings what would go in the `then` block?

```
setup:
def String1 = "books"
def String2 =  new File('/path/to/file').text

when: 
String1 = String1.toLowerCase()
String2 = String2.toLowerCase()

then:
if (String1 == String2) {
    print "file contains the word" + String1
}
```

I need the test to fail when both strings are equal but currently it passes.

Comment: You don't have an expression to test. Your then should be, `string1 ==string2`

Comment: No, it should be `String1 != String2` because the test should fail when they are equal. But please do not use variable names starting with upper-case characters because by convention you would only write class names like that. BTW, the test could also just be: `expect:` (linefeed) `!new File('/path/to/file').text.toLowerCase().contains("books")`. This might be a little less easy to read for some people (easier for me though), but does the same and even expresses that the text file **contains** the word, not that it exactly equals it. I think a test should not be more verbose than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want do this:

```
setup:
def string1 = "books"
def string2 = new File('/path/to/file').text

when:
string1 = string1.toLowerCase()
string2 = string2.toLowerCase()

then:
string1 != string2
```

But you want check, that this two objects are not equals. So in the `when` block, you have to check `equals` method. So your test should look like this:

```
setup:
def string1 = "books".toLowerCase()
def string2 = new File('/path/to/file').text.toLowerCase()

when:
boolean notEquals = string1 != string2

then:
notEquals
```

or shorter:

```
setup:
def string1 = "books".toLowerCase()
def string2 = new File('/path/to/file').text.toLowerCase()

expect:
string1 != string2
```